# Reading from a binary file using fread() displays additional characters

Tags: c, file, binary, fwrite, fread

My question is about this `fread()` function that seems to be confusing for the time being. I create a binary file and put inside of it the values **1**,**2** and **3**. And then I try to read the file and when I do using `fread()` it shows it like **1233** not **123**.

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>     
main ()
{
  int x=1,y=2,z=3,i,j;
  FILE *f;
  f=fopen("Werid.bin","wb");
  fwrite(&x,sizeof(int),1,f);
  fwrite(&y,sizeof(int),1,f);
  fwrite(&z,sizeof(int),1,f);
  fclose(f);
  f=fopen("Werid.bin","rb");
  if (!f) perror("X");
  while(!feof(f))
    {
      fread(&j,sizeof(int),1,f);
      printf("%d",j);
    }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Why?

Comment: `!feof(f)` wrong. check return value of `fread`.

Comment: main must return `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
while(!feof(f))
```

to

```
while(fread(&j,sizeof(int),1,f) == 1)
```

From linux `feof()` manual

> The  function  feof()  tests  the  **end-of-file  indicator** for the stream pointed to by stream, returning nonzero **if it is set**.  The end-of-file indicator can only be
>          cleared by the function clearerr().

The `feof()` will return true after you try to call `fread()` at the end of file i.e. after you read the last number, you will need to call `fread()` again to set the **end-of-file** indicator.

So the loop will be executed one more time after the last read, and since it does not read anything but rather returns an error, it does not change the value of `j` either, so the previous value `3` is printed again.

Comment: Why did that work? Can you elaborate more? @iharob

Comment: @user3785612: Read the question and answer's of which this question is a duplicate.  Basically, you are printing the value before you check whether the last read succeeded, so when it fails, you print the last value a second time, hence the duplicated 3.